# Django template get custom attribute from request OR "refresh" radio buttons

Tags: django, django-templates, radio-button, django-views, forms

I currently have a template containing an html form, with the lines:

```
{% for r in q1.responseoption_set.all %}
     <span class="r"><input type="{{ q1.answer_type }}" name="r{{ r.id }}" id="r{{ forloop.counter }}"/>
     <label {% if q1.answer_type == "text" %}class="textanswer"{% endif %}for="r{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ r.text }}</label></span><br>
{% endfor %}
```

problem is, because they don't all have the same name (that's why, right?), if I pick a radio button, and then switch to another one, the first one still shows as selected.

However, at the moment, I need them to all have different names because I need to be able to identify the choices within my view, and as far as I can tell, all I can get from the request is [name, value], e.g. [r200, "on"]

The only way around this that I can think of is to insert a script that assigns a check event to each button, and then, once checked, inserts a hidden input with the name I want, but that seems messy.

SO, is there a way for me to either:
get the button id from the request OR have the buttons "refresh" somehow as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the name the same, and set the value for each input choice to the answer id.

```
{% for r in q1.responseoption_set.all %}
     <span class="r"><input type="{{ q1.answer_type }}" name="{% questionId %}" value="r{{ r.id }}" id="r{{ forloop.counter }}"/>
     <label {% if q1.answer_type == "text" %}class="textanswer"{% endif %}for="r{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ r.text }}</label></span><br>
{% endfor %}
```